Webassembly WASM is too slow compared with SH shell
I have basic C program (in below) and converting to WASM using emcc to .wasm file.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Iterate from 1 to 10
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; ++i) {
        // Print the current number
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}

However I see, this script takes 40s to finish counting. Even slow shell (/bin/sh) takes 10s.
#!/bin/sh

for i in `seq 1 10000000`;do
    echo $i
done

I wonder is it normal? Almost all forms says webassembly has huge performance benefits.
If I do basic server (while-loop) I think it will be very slow. I can understand manage memory in each iteration could decrease performance, but still I did not expect it is slow than simple BUSYBOX script.
Can anybody provide any WAT file which I can execute in Linux CLI (not in NODEJS) and compare ?
Because wabt project decompile is huge and no sense to optimize it.
I expect .wasm file execution is significant faster than shell

My guess is that you are essentially benchmarking printf, which is slow because of javascript interop resulting in console.log-s. Try benchmarking some pure arithmetic expression, that should be faster.

hmm. It is interesting. Because I removed printf from C code and execution is faster. Can you help me to understand a bit about printing ? I am using wasmer wich for backend runtime env. Not for browser. Do you know in wasmer print works based js methods as well ? or ?
